# Worklight: Encrypted Cache size always increasing - destroy not work

Tags: ios, local-storage, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using `WL.EncryptedCache` and only saving user ID and password throughout the user session and once user session expires or user explicitly logs out from the App, then I am destroying encrypted cache using `WL.EncryptedCache.destroy`.

```
May 13 11:51:55 iPhone CardApp[9836] <Warning>: [LOG] clear badge
May 13 11:51:56 iPhone CardApp[9836] <Warning>: Loading stop
May 13 11:51:56 iPhone CardApp[9836] <Warning>: Original Webview bounds {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}, frame {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
May 13 11:51:56 iPhone CardApp[9836] <Warning>: tabbar bounds: {{0, 411}, {320, 49}}. WebView bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}
May 13 11:51:56 iPhone CardApp[9836] <Warning>: [ERROR] Invalid argument value '[object Object]', expected null or 'string'.
May 13 11:51:57 iPhone CardApp[9836] <Warning>: [ERROR] [https://mydomain:443/myApp/apps/services/api/CardApp/iphone/query] exception.
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x2e4d][9804]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x2e4d]) Exited: Killed: 9
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.tccd[9805]) <Notice>: (com.apple.tccd) Exited: Killed: 9
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.librariand[9840]) <Notice>: (com.apple.librariand) Exited: Killed: 9
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone UserEventAgent[13] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.TextInput.kbd[9823]) <Notice>: (com.apple.TextInput.kbd) Exited: Killed: 9
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x2e4d]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:bh.com.my.CardApp[0xf688][9836]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:bh.com.my.CardApp[0xf688]) Exited: Killed: 9
May 13 11:51:58 iPhone backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:bh.com.my.CardApp[0xf688]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
May 13 11:51:59 iPhone DTPower[5858] <Warning>: Task info failed for task bh.com.my.CardApp
May 13 11:52:01 iPhone ReportCrash[9846] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
May 13 11:52:01 iPhone ReportCrash[9846] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2013-05-13-115201.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
May 13 11:53:59 iPhone backboardd[26] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
May 13 11:53:59 iPhone backboardd[26] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
```

What I see in my iOS 5 device, is that the local storage is always increasing in size of the App folder (documents & data). In my testing I first made sure the app is removed; next I installed it and then three-four times I only logged in and logged-out... and the cache size kept increasing.

As mentioned, on each log out I am calling the destroy method and it is getting executed successfully since after the destroy if I search for keys then they are not there, hence destroyed.

Is there any fix in the latest v5.0.6? Currently I am using v5.0.5
Are there workarounds?

Comment: Post an example please

Comment: <Warning>: [ERROR] Invalid argument value '[object Object]', expected null or 'string'.
Are you SURE the destroy call is working?

Comment: yes , it got deleted, and next time when i search the previous keys then it returns null...it means it deleted Cache.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the [EncryptedCache sample](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced) in Worklight 5.0.6.1 using  Chrome (Windows 7); I can clearly see in the Dev Tools (>> Resources >> Local Storage) the data getting deleted once WL.EncryptedCache.destroy is being invoked.

I don't think it should be any different in iOS 5 or iOS 6.

Note: in iOS 5 Local Storage is considered temporary data that can be deleted at any time by the OS.

Comment: I do agree with you, because in chrome I too have seen it being deleted/overwritten but on device it is behaving as i explained! thanks

Comment: How/where do you notice the file size changes? the sample app is not making large enough changes to actually change the value one can see in Settings >> General >> Storage >> myapp >> Documents & data size. Can you attach your Worklight project?

Comment: Hi, how i can add file? plz guide